# Laravel eloquent: How to filter with where() and whereHas()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to filter my users based on categories in which they have posted something and also the users directly by search string:

```
$users = User::when($search, function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request['search'] . '%')
          ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $request['search'] . '%');

    return $query;
})
->when($categories, function ($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->whereHas('posts.category', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereIn('name', $request['categories']);
    });
})
->select('id', 'name', 'email')
->paginate(10);
```

When I filter for categories only (without `$search`) it is working as expected but as soon as I type a search string the result is filtered by the search string `$request['search']` but ignores the category filtering completely.

So for example:

The user named "Jon" has a post in category "Lifestyle".

Another user named "Jonn" has a post in category "Sports".

Now if I filter for category only "Sports" I get the correct result -> "Jonn".

But if I filter additionally with the search string "Jon" the result is -> "Jon" and "Jonn" which is not the expected result because it should filter for "Sports" and name "%Jon%" so again the result should be only "Jonn".

I don't know how I can achieve that filter combination of `where()` and `whereHas()`.

Comment: for start try with `echo $query_builder->toSql();` to see your final SQL statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is nesting of the constraints. Translated to SQL, your query looks like this:

```
SELECT id, name, email
FROM users
WHERE name like '%foo%'
   OR address like '%foo%'
   OR email like '%foo%'
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM categories c
      INNER JOIN posts p ON p.category_id = c.id
    WHERE c.name IN ('bar', 'baz')
  )
```

*Note: pagination omitted*

As you can see, it isn't quite clear what the `WHERE` statements are supposed to do. But that can be fixed rather easily by wrapping all of the search constraints in an extra `where()`:

```
$users = User::when($search, function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where(function $query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request['search'] . '%')
            ->orWhere('address', 'like', '%' . $request['search'] . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $request['search'] . '%');
    });
})
->when($categories, function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->whereHas('posts.category', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereIn('name', $request['categories']);
    });
})
->select('id', 'name', 'email')
->paginate(10);
```

This way your query will look like this:

```
SELECT id, name, email
FROM users
WHERE
  (
     name like '%foo%'
     OR address like '%foo%'
     OR email like '%foo%'
  )
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM categories c
      INNER JOIN posts p ON p.category_id = c.id
    WHERE c.name IN ('bar', 'baz')
  )
```

A small note on the side: You don't have to return the `$query` from the callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
$users = User::where(function ($query) {
    $query->when($search, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request['search'] . '%')
          ->orWhere('address', 'like', '%' . $request['search'] . '%')
          ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $request['search'] . '%');
        })
    $query->when($categories, function ($query) use ($request) {
           $query->whereHas('posts.category', function ($query) use ($request) {
           $query->whereIn('name', $request['categories']);
        });
    })
})
->select('id', 'name', 'email')
->paginate(10);
```

I think you don't need your return. But you can achieve what do you want if you put your `when` statements in one `where` function like this.

I didn't test this solution so if you have errors provide it in comment.

Good luck!